# Finding the closest 3 values with a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I have a list of employees where the Name, Department and Years of Experience is stated

```
Name    Department  Years of Experience
John    HR                  5
Mary    Finance             12
Tom     HR                  6
Dick    Finance             11
Sally   HR                  8
Harry   Finance             10
Tim     HR                  8
Duke    Finance             9
Simon   HR                  9
Dolly   Finance             2
```

[Reference to the list of Employees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj955.png)

I wish to write a formula where I could input the Department and Years of Experience to serve as a searching criteria - for example: "HR" and "6"
[Input Criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00dg7.png)

```
Search Department:  HR
Years of Experience:    6
```

The results that I am hoping to get would be the Name, Department, and Years of Experience sorted based on how close the employee's experience is based on the searched department.

For example: I searched "HR" and "6", the result will be ordered:
[Displaying of Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2cng.png)

```
Name    Department  Years of Exp
Tom        HR            6
John       HR            5
Sally      HR            8
Tim        HR            8
Simon      HR            9
```

Comment: Do you have FILTER and SORTBY? Then that's what you'll need.

Comment: Yes I do have FILTER and SORTBY, how should I go about writing the formula? Thanks for the prompt reply :)

Answer (score 2):

array formula：

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,RIGHT(SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$11="HR",($C$2:$C$11-6)^2/1%%+ROW($2:$11)),ROW(A1)),2)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: FILTER function]

try having the formula using the FILTER function
just change the ranges as applied to your worksheet

```
=FILTER(B22:D32,C22:C32="HR")
```

Comment: Did you see how OP wants to sort the columns?

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done, using the autofilter basic feature of Excel, why not use that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Option for O365:

```
=LET(sorted,SORTBY(A2:C11,ABS(C2:C11-G2),1),FILTER(sorted,(INDEX(sorted,0,2)=G1)*(INDEX(sorted,0,3)>=G2-3)*(INDEX(sorted,0,3)<=G2+3)))
```

[image]